# Какой структурой лучше воспользоваться для реализации поля игры тетрис? Python

Tags: python-3.x, матрицы, список

На ум приходит несколько вариантов. Матрица (вложенные списки), Список с разделенный на мнимые части как горизонтальные, Несколько списков количество которых равно количеству рядов на поле.

Что выбрать для расчетов положения фигуры на поле, и рисования фигур на поле?

Comment: Битовая матрица проще всего. Или вы хотите помнить местоположение фигуры для каких-то целей?

Comment: @becouse я хочу написать алгоритм что бы игра сама в себя играла

Comment: Тогда битовая матрица лучше всего. А после игры сделаете пошаговый мультик.